# JSONArray not getting properly parsed

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I have a JSONArray which I need to parse. But, the problem is one of the object has only one field, and rest have two fields.

```
{"Event":{
  "Details":[
  {
      "Key" : "AA",
      "Value" : "a"
  },
  {
      "Key" : "BB",
      "Value" :"B"
  },
  {
      "Key" :"CC"
  },
  {
      "Key" :"MIN",
      "Value" : -1
  }
]
}}
```

So, now when I parse it using this code

```
private void parse(String jsonStr) throws JSONException{
    String Value, Key;
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONObject("Event").getJSONArray("Details");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Key = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Key");
        if(Key.equals("CC")){   // make case for null here
            Value = "Something was supposed to be here";
        }

        Object type = array.getJSONObject(i).get("Value");
        //System.out.println("Type: \n"+type.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if(type instanceof String) {
            String ValueStr=array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Value");
            System.out.println(ValueStr);
        } else if(type instanceof Number) {
            Integer ValueInt = array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Value");
            System.out.println(ValueInt);
        }
    }
}
```

It stops parsing after reading "CC". It doesn't even read the next value. The 'Value' for the 'Key' CC is sometimes null, sometimes string. So, how do I catch that? Also, how to continue parsing the next object whenever 'Value' of CC is null?

**EDIT :**   So, I put a try-catch block, but the for-loop isn't even iterating anymore. It goes through the loop only once.

```
for(int i =0; i<array.length() ; i++)
    {
        Key = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Key");

        try
        {           
                 Object type = array.getJSONObject(i).get("Value");
        //System.out.println("Type: \n"+type.getClass().getSimpleName());

            if(type instanceof String)
            {           
                String ValueStr = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Value");
                System.out.println(ValueStr);               
            }

            else if(type instanceof Number)
            {       
                Integer ValueInt = array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Value");
                System.out.println(ValueInt);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Value="something was supposed to be here";
        }

    }
```

Comment: And apparently I can't format my code properly either. :/

Comment: please validate your json first,` "Key" : "AA", "Value" : "a"` should be comma separated values,than try your code

Comment: sorry that was my mistake in typing. The JSONArray is fine, its getting generated in another method. Again, sorry about that. I have edited it now

Comment: @user270386: check the answers given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Durga pointed out in her comment you are missing the commas in you inner json object.

your JSON should be

```
{"Event":{
  "Details":[
  {
      "Key" : "AA", // see the commas here?
      "Value" : "a"
  },
  {
      "Key" : "BB", // see the commas here?
      "Value" :"B"
  },
  {
      "Key" :"CC"
  },
  {
      "Key" :"MIN", // see the commas here?
      "Value" : -1
  }
]
}}
```

and now for the second part, your java code is likely to throw a [JSONException](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONException.html).

Because here

```
Object type = array.getJSONObject(i).get("Value");
```

when iterating over the 3rd element in our array, the object is not having the key `Value`, and hence the `get` call you are placing on the `getJSONObject(i).get("Value")` will throw you a `JSONException` as there is no such key in the object.

See documentation [**here**](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#get(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 2):

Your json is not valid. Please,validate your json and then try your code.

use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your input json.

Comment: Although json input is invalid, it actually doesn't answer the question

Comment: still he would be presented with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your json is not valid
it should be something like that

```
{
"Event": {
    "Details": [
        {
            "Key": "AA",
            "Value": "a"
        },
        {
            "Key": "BB",
            "Value": "B"
        },
        {
            "Key": "CC"
        },
        {
            "Key": "MIN",
            "Value": -1
        }
    ]
}
```

}

now your parsing code need to be check for "Value" key to exist if it exist then only get the value for "Value" key

```
private void parse(String jsonStr) throws JSONException
{

    String Value, Key;
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONObject("Event").getJSONArray("Details");
    for(int i =0; i<array.length() ; i++)
    {
        Key = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Key");

        //if(Key.equals("CC"))    // comment this
        if(!array.getJSONObject(i).has("Value")) //if "Value" key is not exist
        {
            Value = "Something was supposed to be here";
        }
        else //if "Value" key exist
        {
           //do whatever u like
           Object type = array.getJSONObject(i).get("Value");
           if(type instanceof String)
           {           
            String ValueStr=array.getJSONObject(i).getString("Value");
            System.out.println(ValueStr);               
            }

            else if(type instanceof Number)
            {       
            Integer ValueInt = array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Value");
            System.out.println(ValueInt);
            }
        }
        //Object type = array.getJSONObject(i).get("Value");//put this line inside else part
        //System.out.println("Type: \n"+type.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
 }
```

Comment: -1. you are still having a problem. `Object type = array.getJSONObject(i).get("Value");` will still,certainly, throw an exception. it should be restructured. you should probably put that inside the else block. Moreover your design of the if else block is quite wrong. why are you negating a condition when you can simply swap the code in the else to the if block and vice-versa and remove the negation?

Comment: I have removed the downvote as the exception is now prevented. but the if block can be improved. remove the negation operator and swap the code in the if and else blocks. `if(true){ do A} else { do B} is always gud than, if(!true) {do B} else { do A}`